# Bootstrap: Email field has smaller height than text field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with both text and email fields.  Bootstrap consistently renders the email field with a smaller height than the text or password fields. Any idea how to fix this?
I'm using the rails tags 'text_field' and 'email_field' to generate the forms.

Comment: Provide the markup and a [suitable and working demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net) as part of your answer. I'd say the odds are it's a CSS or HTML problem. Wait, Javascript! If we're guessing. Advice? Use a console to inspect the element and find out where the height's being set, and neutralize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the font size of each field's div with the css `font-size` property.

Example (in your css file):

```
div.email_field {
    font-size: 16px;
}
div.text_field {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```